# Unable to upload file with Cordova FileTransfer

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, upload, file-transfer

I am trying to upload a file using upload method from FileTransfer Cordova plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). Finally I almost copied the example mentioned on project's page, but still without success - the method fires success callback function, but targeted script doesn't receive the file nor any of the params. My code is:

*Calling function:*

```
var fleNme = TOP_APP_DIR + "/config/config.json";

fileAPI.readFile(fleNme, function (data) {
    console.log("File content: " + data); // just to meake sure the file exists and it contains some data

    fileAPI.uploadFile("http://posttestserver.com/post.php", fleNme, { par1: "test", par2: "test2" }, null, function (r) {
            console.log("Successful upload...");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
    });
});
```

*Upload function:*

```
fileAPI.uploadFile = function (url, filePath, params, progressFunc, successCallback, failCallback, FStype) {
    if (typeof failCallback === "undefined" || failCallback === null)
        failCallback = fileAPI.defaultErrorCallback;

    // getFileEntry method is used for reading the file before call the upload method, so it's OK
    fileAPI.getFileEntry(filePath, function (fileEntry) {
        var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = "text/plain";
        options.httpMethod = "POST";

        if(typeof params === "undefined" || params === null)
            params = {};

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();

        ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI(url), successCallback, failCallback, options);
    }, failCallback,FStype,false);
};
```

*Output in my console is:*

- File content: {"version":9,"timeStamp":1480793843086,"language":"cs" ........
- Successful upload...
- {"response":"Successfully dumped 0 post variables.\nView it at http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2016/12/03/11.41.062096548295\nPost body was 0 chars long.","responseCode":200,"objectId":"","bytesSent":522}

*Log from posttestserver.com is:*

```
Time: Sat, 03 Dec 16 11:41:06 -0800
Source ip: 31.30.45.209

Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
REQUEST_URI = /post.php
QUERY_STRING = 
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REMOTE_PORT = 48730
REMOTE_ADDR = 31.30.45.209
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = gzip
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; SM-T320     Build/KOT49H)
CONTENT_TYPE = multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++
UNIQUE_ID = WEMf0kBaMGUAAFmEWtgAAAAK
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT = 1480794066.2475
REQUEST_TIME = 1480794066

No Post Params.
Empty post body.

== Multipart File upload. ==
Received 0 file(s)
```

I target Cordova CLI 6.1.1. I spent whole day trying different approaches, but always I got the same result. I debuged the code on 3 different Android devices - HTC 10, Samsung Galaxy Tab SM-T320 and some old Prestigio mobile phone - with the same result. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Try adding `options.chunkedMode = false` and see if that helps.

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks. In case you write it as answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Added as an answer. :-) Glad you got things working. Be on the lookout for a fresh plugin drop soon -- you might want to try it and see if it addresses the issue with chunkedMode set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen a lot of problems with the default setting of `chunkedMode` (which is `true`). Switching to `options.chunckedMode = false` should help the problem.